# Languages with capitalization inside or at the end of certain words

Tags: orthography, list-of-languages

I recently asked myself this seemingly simple question, but could not find any answers on my own.
Are there any natural (or constructed) languages that capitalize (depending on their alphabet of course) in a different way than English, German and the like? So, instead of

> **T**his is my friend **B**ob.

they might do something like

> thi**S** is my friend bo**B**.

Before you ask, no, I'm not asking for `ltr`-languages that capitalize the beginning of their words. I'm asking for any language (with a capitalization possible) where names, proper nouns or whatever else gets capitalized not at the beginning, but at the ending or even the middle of their words.

P.S.: I'm aware of some hyphenated words that have a kind of camel case, especially in German. I'm not looking for that.

Comment: If you count *quadcameral* (unlike *bicameral*) scripts, one obvious answer would be [Arabic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Letter_forms), where each letter can have 2 to 4 distinct forms (initial, middle, final, and isolated). Hence, every word would have `3←[…2←]2←1` form, where 1, 2, and 3 are the initial, middle, and final letter forms, correspondingly. So, **the final form** may or may not be an answer, depending on your understanding of the question.

Comment: Oh, nice suggestion. I didn't know that the styles are counted as "camerals" (New term as well, thank you Sir)

Comment: See also Greek final Sigma, copied in English as a final alternate to Long S until 1800. And also Hebrew Sophith letters, like the square final Mem or the long final Pe.

Comment: Klingon? No, not really.

Comment: If you are really asking about "special words" and not about words in general, then Arabic, Hebrew and Greek are totally irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @fdb Ah, sorry, wondered about that right now too. I didn't want to write 'nouns' and the like in the title, I'll change it

Comment: Your question is fine as it stands. I was merely responding to some of the comments on here.

Comment: @fdb Ah, now I get what you mean. Yeah, I went and prettified it anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Zulu language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_language) does not capitalise noun class markers but capitalises the proper noun itself, as in the name of the language *isiZulu* (*isi-* is the singular noun class 7 marker).

Also, in Irish Gaelic orthography, the [mutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_initial_mutations) of capitalised nouns are not capitalised, for instance *nGaillimh*, the nasal mutation of *Gaillimh* 'Galway'.

*(As Colin Fine points out in a comment, Klingon perhaps, although the capitals in romanisation can distinguish different sounds, and unlike Gaelic and Zulu orthography, are nothing to do with the uppercasing convention for proper nouns :)*

Comment: Also: Paul McCartney

Answer (score 5):

Italian does this for [formal letter writing](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/lettere-commerciali-e-ufficiali-prontuario_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/):

- ***informarLa*** = *informare* (to inform) + [*La*](https://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/la#ctl00_cC_collinsResultsDiv) (you [formal direct object pronoun])
- ***portarGliela*** = *portare* (to give) + [*Gli*](https://dictionary.reverso.net/italian-english/gli#ctl00_cC_collinsResultsDiv) (to you [formal indirect object pronoun]) + *la* (it)

Notice that *La* ≠ *la*.

Answer (score 4):

Javanese has 8 letters that are used instead of ordinary letters in all positions (initial, medial, final) in certain proper names. They are called “aksara murda” or “huruf kapital”. You can find them here: https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aksara_Murda (in Indonesian only).

Comment: Aksara Murda are given in the English article on Javanese script, too. They are in the script chart, called simply 'Murda', and their use is described below the chart. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_script#Aksara